# Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException in android studio

Tags: java, android

i have 6 layouts and each layout having two button back and next..without button back and next application runs properly but when i put code in back and next button having name button 7 is used for back and button 8 is used for next layout it gives me a error null exception.

```
ImageButton btn1;
ImageButton btn2;
ImageButton btn3;
ImageButton btn4;
ImageButton btn5;
ImageButton btn6;
ImageButton btn7;
ImageButton btn8;
ImageView view;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    addListenerOnButton7();
    //addListenerOnButton8();
    addListenerOnButton();
    addListenerOnButton2();
    addListenerOnButton3();
    addListenerOnButton4();
    addListenerOnButton5();
    addListenerOnButton6();
```

public void addListenerOnButton7() {

```
    btn7= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn7);
    btn7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View view)
                                {

                                    setContentView(R.layout.show);
                                    Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
                                }

                            }
    );
}
```

public void addListenerOnButton() {

```
    btn1= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            setContentView(R.layout.show);
            Runtime.getRuntime().gc();

            }



    }
    );
}

public void addListenerOnButton2() {

    btn2= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View view)
                                {
                                    setContentView(R.layout.k2);
                                    Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
                                }
                            }
    );
}

public void addListenerOnButton3() {

    btn3= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn3);
    btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View view)
                                {
                                    setContentView(R.layout.k3);
                                    Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
                                }
                            }
    );
}

public void addListenerOnButton4() {

    btn4= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn4);
    btn4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View view)
                                {
                                    setContentView(R.layout.k4);
                                    Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
                                }
                            }
    );
}

public void addListenerOnButton5() {

    btn5= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn5);
    btn5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View view)
                                {
                                    setContentView(R.layout.k5);
                                    Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
                                }
                            }
    );
}

public void addListenerOnButton6() {

    btn6= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn6);
    btn6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View view)
                                {
                                    setContentView(R.layout.k6);
                                    Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
                                }
                            }
    );
}
```

Comment: Post your whole code and logcat

Comment: you are probably not referencing the correct layout in the fragment/activity, but you need to post more code.. a lot more.

Comment: wrong way of using layout. you need to use layout by creating from another activity and by using Intent you need to launch.

Answer (score 1):

You already use it in there

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code, it looks like it comes from inside an activity so you need to call `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` in the `onCreate()` of your activity before `btn7= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn7);` and that should fix the NullPointer.

Comment: i use these two buttons for next and previous purpose..so i dont know why it gives me a error